# Inspect an object and perform modifications on all matching child nodes

Tags: javascript, postman, newman

I'm working with a large JSON configuration file (incidentally, a collection of Postman/Newman API requests) and need to perform some modifications on this before running it in a Node app.

#### Sample configuration

```
let config = {
  "name": "API Requests",
  "item": [
    {
      "name": "Upload Data File",
      "body": {
        "formdata": [
          {
            "key": "filerename",
            "value": "./tests/fixtures/data.txt",
            "type": "text"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Another Group",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "Upload Profile Photo",
          "body": {
            "formdata": [
              {
                "key": "filerename",
                "value": "./tests/fixtures/profilephoto.png",
                "type": "text"
              },
              {
                "key": "anotherkey",
                "value": "1",
                "type": "text"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

function updateFormdataObjects(config) {
  let updatedConfig;
  // Process the object here and rewrite each of the formdata entries as described below
  return updatedConfig;
}
```

#### Required steps

1) Search inside `config` to find all children which contain a `"key": "filerename"`

2) For each matching child, modify their keys and values as follows:

```
// Original object
{
  "key": "filerename",
  "value": "./tests/fixtures/anotherphoto.png",
  "type": "text"
}

// Updated object
{
  "key": "file",                               // change the value from "filerename" to "file"
  "src": "./tests/fixtures/anotherphoto.png",  // change the key from "value" to "src"
  "type": "file"                               // change the value from "text" to "file"
}
```

3) Once complete, return the entire modified object.

#### Notes

- There may be many matching children within the main object. All of them need to be processed.
- The object can have infinite levels of nesting, so the function should accommodate this.
- The function should return a single modified object which can then be used elsewhere
- I'm running this script as part of a Node app with ES6, so can make the most of

Comment: Are you just finding and replacing text in a JSON file? Can you not use a text editor like sublime, VSCode etc?

Comment: @DannyDainton Unfortunately not, because the set of requests (there are about 400 of them) is updated quite regularly and exported to JSON. This script then needs to process that JSON file and make the necessary adjustments before running Newman on the CLI. The example up above is a massively abbreviated version of the real configuration ;)

Comment: What does the export? Can it not be handled before that stage rather than after it?

Comment: Unfortunately not - there are some limitations in the generating app (Postman) which mean that we have to make the modifications via a script after the export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to avoid stringifying the JSON and then running a Regex replace on it, because I thought this would be less versatile in the future. But it seemed like the simplest approach for now:

```
function replaceFilePaths(input) {
    let modified = JSON.stringify(input);
    modified = modifiedCollection.replace(/{\"key\":\"filekey\[(.*?)\]\",\"value\":\"(.*?)\",\"type\":\"text\"}/mg, '{"key":"\$1","src":"\$2","type": "file"}')
    return JSON.parse(modified);
}
```

I also made an adjustment to allow a bit more configuration over the key name by allowing to pass in a key name like `filekey[file_url]` and turning this into `"key": "file_url"`.